# Search a letter in a list of words?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array called 'words' storing many words.

For example:
I have `'systematic', 'سلام','gear','synthesis','mysterious', etc.`

NB: we have **utf8** words too.
How to query efficiently to see which words include letters `'s','m','e'` (all of them) ?

The output would be:

```
systematic,mysterious
```

I have no idea how to do such a thing in PHP. It should be efficient because our server would suffer otherwise.e.

Comment: Loop through the array, investigating each element with `strpos`. If `strpos` returns `> 0`, then add that element to a different array, which will hold all matched elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked to me:

```
$words = array('systematic', 'سلام','gear','synthesis','mysterious');
$letters=array('s','m', 'e');
foreach ($words as $w) {
  //print "lets check word $w<br>";
  $n=0;
  foreach ($letters as $l) {
     if (strpos($w, $l)!==false) $n++;
  }
  if ($n>=3) print "$w<br>";
}
```

It returns

```
systematic
mysterious
```

#### Explanation

- It uses nested `foreach`: one for the words and the other one for the letters to be matched.
- In case any letter is matched, the counter is incremented.
- Once the letters loop is over, it checks how many matches were there and prints the word in case it is `3`.

Comment: I checked your code with wincacheGrind, your code was faster than other codes. Without using many functions your work was the best.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression to split each string into an array of characters, and use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/array_intersect) to find out if all the characters in your search array is present in the split array:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf8');

$words = array('systematic', 'سلام','gear','synthesis','mysterious');
$search = array('s','m','e');

foreach ($words as $word) {
    $char_array = utf8_str_split($word);
    $contains = array_intersect($search, $char_array) == $search;
    echo sprintf('%s : %s', $word, (($contains) ? 'True' : 'False'). PHP_EOL);
}

function utf8_str_split($str) {
    return preg_split('/(?!^)(?=.)/u', $str);
}
```

Output:

```
systematic : True
سلام        : False
gear       : False
synthesis  : False
mysterious : True
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/80256)

---

**UPDATE:** Or, alternatively, you could use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match):

```
$array = array_filter($words, function($item) {
    return preg_match('~(?=[^s]*s)(?=[^m]*m)(?=[^e]*e)~u', $item);
});
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => systematic
    [4] => mysterious
)
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/80284)

Comment: @RishabhRaj: I think it is. Could you point out the mistake, if there is any?

Comment: aah sorry my bad i didnot see true ,false .+1 :)

Comment: You have used preg_match that kills the app from performance point of view. Your code was not the fastest. but thanks anyway

Comment: @phpGeek: Yes, `preg_` functions are slow. However, the accepted solution does not handle non-English words.

Comment: Actually it returns utf8 words too. I've tested it myself now.

Comment: @phpGeek: Ah, I just tested it myself now and it works well :)

Comment: Your code is 200ms slower than @fedorqui . I've checked it by winCachegrind

Comment: Just for the record, what is the execution time of each one of the scripts, @phpGeek ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$words = array('systematic', 'سلام','gear','synthesis','mysterious');
$result=array();

foreach($words as $word){
  if(strpos($word, 's') !== false &&
     strpos($word, 'm') !== false &&
     strpos($word, 'e') !== false){
       $result[] = $word;
  }
}
echo implode(',',$result); // will output 'systematic,mysterious'
```

Comment: It's not flexible if I add a few more letters. thanks for the answer by the way. +1

Answer (score 0):

Your question is wide a little bit. 
What I understand from your question that's those words are saved in a database table, so you may filter the words before getting them into the array, using SQL like function.

in case you want to search for a letters in an array of words, you could loop over the array using foreach and each array value should be passed to strpos function.
http://www.php.net/function.strpos

Answer (score 0):

why not use [PREG_GREP](http://php.net/preg_grep)

```
$your_array = preg_grep("/[sme]/", $array);

print_r($your_array);
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://3v4l.org/nIRbe)

Comment: It loops through the array itself?

Comment: @phpGeek ya it will search whole array.go through the link i provided.

Comment: @plaes sorry it wasnot meant for you :)

Comment: @plaes can u please elaborate why?

Comment: You are currently returning word if any of the characters is present, but all the characters should be present. It took a bit figuring out what was wrong (as it wasn't obvious). That's why I wrote the "please add demo output here".

Comment: @plaes aah that means we just need to change the regex,but the approach is correct and short.:)

Comment: +1, thanks your demo works as it should. but you should pay careful attention that I want it for utf8 ones too. Thanks anyway. +1